# Custom tabbar below navigationcontroller issue iphone

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have created a custom scrollable tabbar [scrollview with buttons over it] below navigationcontroller. I have two tabbars already in standard tabcontroller at the bottom. For the standard bottom tabs, I have created two navigationcontrollers in xib with two different nibs for both. I'm loading a tableview in one of the lower tabs which is common to one of the upper tabs which is having the navigationcontroller reference.

The issue is in the second upper tab I'm having a viewController but it's not having the navigationcontroller reference as I am not able to give its reference in my main.xib to the upper tab as that tab is not an actual tab with respect to the xib.

I tried giving the app delegate's navigationcontroller outlet reference to locally created navigationcontroller in that particular viewcontroller without the navigation reference. So the otherwise nil navigationcontroller reference isn't coming nil now and showing me the app delegate's navigationcontroller reference when logged, but I'm still not able to change its title or any of the barbuttons for that matter.

I want to know wheather it's really possible to have standard tabbar with different viewcontrollers as well as upper tabbar with its own different tabs and viewcontrollers along with navigation reference for each?

I have seen such app but in that case each of the upper tabs are having the same view for example tableview only different datasource for each tab which is possible as you already have a viewcontroller's reference in one of the lower tabs which you can keep common to all the upper tabs.

This is the screenshot of the setup.

[image]

Upper tabbar contains two tabs: Newsfeed and Top 1000 companies.
The tableview in Newsfeed is actually the nib file which is loaded inside lower tab Newsfeed. But the other upper tab "Top 1000 companies"'s nib isn't loaded in this setup as the upper tabbar is just virtual. So in this setup I'm not able to give navigationcontroller's reference to the "Top 1000 companies"'s viewcontroller.

Thanx in advance.

This' really urgent.

Comment: Sweet lord, this is a complicated setup. Could you post a screenshot of your app or some wireframes of what you want to achieve, because, to be honest with you, I did't understand a) what you want to do and b) what the problem is.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, I found out the answer for this question. Many a times doing things programmatically than through interface builder helps.